# Sticky image while text scrolls

Tags: html, css

I am creating a div which have an image and text flexed as a row. The desired effect I am trying to achieve is that when I scroll through the div, the text that is at the center of the div will move down while the image stays constant. I am using sticky position for the image to achieve this but there seems to be a problem in my approach. I am attaching part of my code below.

for reference this is the effect I want https://codepen.io/_catherinemc/pen/yKGvGM

```css
.story3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(21, 0, 255);
  height: 100vh;
}

.tft {
  position: sticky;
}

.tft img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 45rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="story3">


    <p class="header">Text of the div that will scroll down </p>

    <div class="tft">
      <img src="14.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <p>Text below used for scroll </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sticky property requires you to define either a "top", "left", "bottom", or "right" property as well.

```js
   

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const header = document.querySelector(".header");
  const tft = document.querySelector(".tft");
  const offset = tft.offsetHeight;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    header.style.transform = "translateY(" + scrollPosition + "px)";
  });
});
```

```css
  

.story3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(21, 0, 255);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto; /* container is scrollable */
}

.tft {
  width: 50%;
}

.tft img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* Maintain aspect ratio of the image */
}

.header {
  margin: 0; /* Remove default margin on paragraph */
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 45rem;
}
```

```html
   

<div class="story3">
  <div class="tft">
    <img src="14.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <p class="header">Text of the div that will scroll down </p>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <p>Text below used for scroll </p>
</div>
```

Also ensure that the container is scrollable.